# Bad request when i am adding video to playlist

Tags: c#, windows-8, youtube-api

I am trying to add youtube video to the watch later playlist, but in response I am getting a Bad request error.

```
var request = new HttpRequest<YoutubePlaylistItem>();

request.Path = "/v3/playlistItems";
request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
request.AddParameter("part", "snippet");
request.AddParameter("key", ApiKey);

if (this.authorizationData != null)
{
      request.Headers.Add("Authorization",
      this.authorizationData.TokenType + " " + this.authorizationData.AccessToken);
}

var playlistItem = new YoutubePlaylistItem();
playlistItem.Snippet = new YoutubeVideoSnippet();
playlistItem.Snippet.PlaylistId = playlistId;
playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId = new ResourceId();
playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId = videoId;
playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.Kind = "youtube#video";
request.PostContent.Add(playlistItem);

var test = await request.SendAsync();
```

When i tried this request in API Explorer, it works fine. Any ideas why this does not work in my application?

Comment: Could you give more details of the error? Have you looked at it in something like Fiddler?

Comment: @paul-zahra When i use fiddler my app froze and cant send any request. Error do not have any details, just 401 bad request

Comment: error 401 is for unauthorized action

Comment: Indeed, so is it a 400 Bad Request or a 401 Unauthorized ?